# React fetch POST request not working in only safari

Tags: reactjs, http, post, safari, fetch-api

For some reason trying to do a POST request on safari doesn't work despite it working on chrome for me. https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch suggests that fetch should work on safari, and the GET requests do work just fine.

My code looks like

```
putData() {
    let data = {
      title: this.state.tempTitle,
      lat: this.state.tempLat,
      lng: this.state.tempLng,
      insta: this.state.tempInsta,
      icon: this.state.tempType,
      approved: false,
    };
    let options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      mode: 'cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
    fetch("/items/", options);
  }
```

Other similar/same questions on stack overflow suggested adding the `mode: 'cors'` line as well as changing `/items` to `/items/` but, I have tried without those two changes to my code as well.

Response preview on safari says `An error occurred when trying to load resource` and the request headers page for items/ shows

```
Summary
URL: http://localhost:3000/items/
Status: —
Source: —
Initiator: 
Suggest.js:62


Request
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:3000/suggest
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15

Response
No response headers
```

Confused as to why this might be happening, didn't even notice till I uploaded the site to AWS and someone using it noticed on their iPhone.

Comment: What are the exact error messages that Safari is logging in the Web Inspector console?

Comment: @sideshowbarker no errors showing in console